# Setting values of material from geometry nodes

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

Sorry if this is something really obvious, I'm sort of new to geometry nodes. I have a simple geometry nodes setup that distributes picture frames on a mesh. These picture frames also have a procedural slashing effect with different values that control the effect. I can't for the life of me figure out how to control the material with geonodes... For the geonodes setup, I have the modifier applied to a cube. It uses "distribute points on faces," "instance on points," and "rotate instances" to place the portraits. For the shader, there are 5 values I want to be able to control, all floats (unless there's an easier way to randomize the images? My current idea is to input a random float, and then determine the image based on the value).

[image: My geonodes setup]

[image]

I've been trying to figure this out for a while with no luck, so any help is appreciated ^^'

Answer (score 3):

Using geometry nodes, you can set attributes on shaders for any value type, including floats.

### First, add an output to your Geometry Nodes group.

[image: geo node output]

### Second, in the Geometry Node settings, create a new attribute for the output.

[image: geo settings]

### Third, capture the attribute in the shader.

[image: shader settings]

Profit.

Here's a demo of it working:
[image: demo]

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this didn't work for me. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S9IMZGjT3DZ_omKfcQbCPCSc1RKBHzK3/) is my blend file. If you could check it out and tell me what I'm missing, it would be very very very appreciated

Comment: NVM, I got it! The solution was surprisingly easy, I just had to use object info in the shading editor